# LiveChat on Scratch Org

Tags: liveagent, salesforcedx, scratch-org

I think there is a problem with enabling Live Agent on Scratch Orgs. Even that I have "IsLiveAgentEnabled" added to scratch org definition file created scratch orgs don't have licences to use Live Agent.

Here is sample of my scratch org definition file:

```
"country": "US",
"edition": "Enterprise",
"features": "PersonAccounts;ServiceCloud",
"orgPreferences": {
    "enabled": [
        "S1DesktopEnabled",
        "IsKnowledgeEnabled",
        "IsLiveAgentEnabled"
    ],
    "disabled": []
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Live Agent is Currently supported only on Developer Edition according to this  [KNOWLEDGE ARTICLE](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000268865&language=en_US&type=1).

Here is a sample Scratch org definition file I'm using to create a Scratch org with LiveAgent and PersonAccount Enabled.

```
{
"orgName": "Company Name",
"country": "FR",
"language": "en_US",
"edition": "Developer",
"orgPreferences" : {
    "enabled": ["S1DesktopEnabled", "IsQuoteEnabled", "IsForecastsEnabled", 
        "ChatterEnabled", "EnhancedEmailEnabled", "EventLogWaveIntegEnabled",
        "Translation", "IsLiveAgentEnabled", "IsKnowledgeEnabled",
        "SocialProfilesEnable", "IsActivityRemindersEnabled", "IsDragAndDropSchedulingEnabled", 
        "IsEmailTrackingEnabled", "IsGroupTasksEnabled", "IsMultidayEventsEnabled", 
        "IsRecurringEventsEnabled", "IsRecurringTasksEnabled", "IsSidebarCalendarShortcutEnabled",
        "IsSimpleTaskCreateUIEnabled", "ShowHomePageHoverLinksForEvents", "ShowMyTasksHoverLinks"]
},
"features" : [ "MultiCurrency", "PersonAccounts", "ServiceCloud",
        "Communities", "CustomerSelfService", "CustomApps", "API", "CustomTabs", "DefaultWorkflowUser",
         "LightningServiceConsole", "LightningSalesConsole", "CustomApps"]
}
```

Comment: I've got same confirmation from SFDC support. Problem comes when you use LiveChat which is only on developer and PersonAccount which is not on developer edition :/

Comment: Yes there are come incompatibilities as all features and Org Preferences are not yet available on all Editions. But the one I clearly identified is the use of SocialProfile + LiveAgent. The first is available only on Enterprise Edition and the latest on Developer Edition. But PersonAccount and LiveAgent are both available on Developer Edition.

Comment: My experience shows that it's not :(

Comment: I edited the answer to add a sample Scratch Org Definition File that enable LiveAgent and PersonAccount

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming upon this and developing second generation packages (2GP), `orgPreferences` has been deprecated.

See [this Salesforce blog post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/02/features-and-settings-and-scratch-orgs-oh-my.html) for information on enabling features in scratch orgs.

The [Metadata coverage report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/48) also has a handy scratch org settings generator.